# Передать исключение в другую функцию JS

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
function getData() {

    try {
        if (data !== 0) {
            //какая-то логик
            return value;
        } else {
            throw 'err null '; //выбрасываю исключение если 0
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR ' + e)
    }
}
```

Есть функция которая принимает возвращенное значение

```
function setData() {
try {
var a=1;
console.log(a+getData());
}
 catch (e) {
        console.log(e); // не срабатывает
    }
}
```

Как мне перекинуть исключение из одной функции в другую?

Comment: А зачем это нужно?

Comment: Ну, что бы потом понимать, где что и какое выбросило исключение. И передать это дальше

Comment: Можно внутри `catch (e)` снова сделать `throw e`, тогда исключение полетит дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы сделать то, что Вы хотите, надо создавать новое исключение в блоке `catch`, тогда исключение будет перехвачено вызывающей функцией:

```
 function getData() {
    try {
        if (data !== 0) {
            //какая-то логик
            return value;
        } else {
            throw 'err null '; //выбрасываю исключение если 0
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR ' + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#Examples

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, я бы разделил исключения на типы. Для того, чтобы их разделить на типы  нам необходимо реализовать свои исключения:

```js
/**
 * Parent Exception
 */
class DefaultException extends Error {
  
  /**
   * @param {string} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
  }
}

class GetDataException extends DefaultException {

  /**
   * @param {string} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

class SetDataException extends DefaultException {

  /**
   * @param {string} message
   */
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

В будущем это можно будет и оснастить разной логикой. Теперь обновим ваш код:

```
function getData() {
    try {
        if (data !== 0) {
            //какая-то логика
            return value;
        } else {
            throw new GetDataException('Ошибка получения информации');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof GetDataException) {
          // Можно прокинуть это исключение в какой-то обработчик
        }

        // В остальных случаях
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Аналогично с функций `setData`.